# Don't know where to add pod files flutter ios installation

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I am working on a flutter project with a firebase backend and am trying to add the ios aspect of my project to a firebase project.  The directions say to add the following pods:

```
# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

but the issue is I have no idea where to write these in the file.  Here is the file located here (ios/Podfile).  Can someone who is more familiar with ios development please show me where to add these pods?  Thanks!

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks again!  I also might have another file.  Do they mean the Podfile.lock file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to add those lines to the 'Podfile' file, not Podfile.lock. You can add the line at the beginning or the end, but adding it to the very beginning is probably good so you can easily see how the default file has been modified.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

...
```

Another thing to keep in mind is when adding your GoogleServices-Info.plist file, you have to add the file in xcode. You can just drag the file into the Runner directory in xcode. But it's not enough to, for example, just download that file into the correct folder.

Comment: Thanks @Kris! Huge help!

Comment: Such tiny editions are rejected but... **you have to add the file in xcode** deserves a bold!  xD  Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a xcode now. What should I do?